# Write to the second line of a PHP file

Tags: php, file-io

I have a php file that I want to add an include path to on the second line. I need to open the file and inset a line of code on line 2.

I have tried a few techniques none of which are working but I think it has something to do with the text I am trying to write and possibly not escaping character correctly as I am not too familiar with file writing.

So here is the file I want to write to:

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$domaindir.'/test.php';
```

Here is the piece of text I want to insert into the file:

```
$dbfile = "include('".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$domaindir."/web_".$dbname.".inc.php');";
```

Then what I was doing was a string replace but all it did was bump the "session_start();" bit to a newline!

Can anyone point me in the direction of a tutorial that might tell me how to insert this into the second line of my php file or indeed if anyone has any ideas?

I can say for sure that the path to the PHP file is fully tested so i know its not that the file is not being open or written to.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: php file modification from php is a terrible idea. What do you need it for?

Comment: you haven't show how you open the file, do the replace, etc.  The two strings you provide aren't much help without more code.

Comment: `http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php`

Comment: I agree with @zerkms. Certainly modifying the script should not be necessary. You should at least be able to set Global Variables or something. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: You either want to create some sort of website infecting worm, or you have a really bad application design for a huge website with no central originating execution path. Either way, because not beeing able to solve this yourself, you will definitely get yourself in trouble later (maybe as far as destroying some code - make sure you backup what you want to alter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After wholly agreeing with zerkms - PHP file modification is a **Bad Idea** - you do not need replacements to do this.

Just read the file in with file(), which places your PHP file in a convenient array. Then you may splice the array, or possibly:

```
$file       = file('yourfile.php');

$first_line = array_shift($file);       // Remove first line and save it
array_unshift($file, $yourSecondLine);  // push second line
array_unshift($file, $first_line);      // Save back the first line

$fp = fopen('yourfile.php', 'w');       // Reopen the file
fwrite($fp, implode("\n", $file));     
fclose($fp);
```

**Check file permissions** after you have done this. They might have become more relaxed (or less. If you run this from command line as root recursively on a web tree, with most Apache installations you will find yourself with **a unusable web site** since Apache will no longer be able to access files that are now born-again superuser files).

Comment: ok ill give that a shot but I will be taking everyones advice here that its a bad idea to do this. I must figure out a better way of dynamically creating a db connection file which has to sit outside of the website root.

Comment: *Why* must it sit outside the website root? Not for security, surely?